# Sending file using JSFtp and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sftp

I want to send a file using JSFTP.
First I have to create a folder where i will put the files. 
This is working fine, so the connection is OK.
But when i want to upload the file I got this :

```
DEBUG:  user_command
"stor fo994201-836f-48d0-925b-52068b8a49be/20160511/undefined"
DEBUG:  response
{
  "code": 550,
  "text": "550 '' was not found.",
  "isMark": false,
  "isError": true
}
{ [Error: 550 '' was not found.] code: 550 }
```

I can't understand why i got : undefined in the stor command...
This is the portion of code which creat the folder and sent files :

```
//Create the new folder
Ftp.raw.mkd("fo994201-836f-48d0-925b-52068b8a49be/"+date, function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(data);

  console.log("Trying to Upload file.");
  for (var i=1; i<filenames.length; i++){
      console.log (" Sending : " + filenames[i]);
      fs.readFile(path+date+'/'+filenames[i], "binary", function(err, data) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(data, "binary");
        Ftp.put(buffer, 'fo994201-836f-48d0-925b-52068b8a49be/'+date+'/'+filenames[i], function(err) {
              if (err){
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              console.log("File uploaded successfully");
          }
          setTimeout(function(){}, 20000);
        });
      });
  }
});
```

Debug output :

```
Trying to Upload file.
 Sending : test.txt
DEBUG:  user_command
"pasv"
DEBUG:  response
{
  "code": 227,
  "text": "227 Entering Passive Mode (54,194,108,219,214,8)",
  "isMark": false,
  "isError": false
}
DEBUG:  user_command
"stor fo994201-836f-48d0-925b-52068b8a49be/20160511/undefined"
DEBUG:  response
{
  "code": 550,
  "text": "550 '' was not found.",
  "isMark": false,
  "isError": true
}
{ [Error: 550 '' was not found.] code: 550 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution : If you want to use extension file you need to use mput and not put.
So It's working with mput.